# Phaser isometric map. How to set its bounds?

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework, isometric

I  need help in setting the world bounds in Phaser (isometric plugin in use). The problem here, I think, is that **"game.world.setBounds(...)"** is set in screen coordinates and not in isometric map coordinates.

To illustrate this:
(the black border represents the map border)

[image: How I would like the bounds to be]

[image: How I think they are beeing set]

I would like the map bounds to be like in the first image. Any ideia how can I do this?

Comment: I know there's isometric plugin for phaser.js described [here](https://developer.tizen.org/community/tip-tech/creating-isometric-world-phaser.js-using-isometric-plugin) but I've never used it.

Comment: Yes you are right. Lately I have started to believe that the bounds I set are actually like in the first image. It is just a little bit difficult to calculate the exact coordinates to set the bound to. But I think I will work it out.

Comment: Oh sorry, I didn't saw you already use this plugin. I'll rethink this.